# Convert object values to new array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

This is my object:

```
"names": [{
        "first": "Linda"
    },
    {
        "first": "Maverick"
    },
];
```

How can I convert this, so that I get an array with just the `first` values:

```
["Linda", "Maverick"]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
data.names.map(name => name.first)
```

Answer (score 7):

Simply use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
let data = {"names": [
  {"first": "Linda"},
  {"first": "Maverick"},
]};

let array = data.names.map(name => name.first);

console.log(array)
```

Answer (score 4):

Use map with destructuring:

```js
var names = [
  {
    "first": "Linda"
  },
  {
    "first": "Maverick"
  },
];

var res = names.map(({
  first
}) => first);
console.log(res);
```